# Adding a simple DOM manipulation JS script via Interop

Tags: c#, interop, blazor

I am trying to import this Javascript function into my Blazor application. The function of the script is simple, add the class `c-show` into an existing list `<li>` element that already has two classes. The original javascript in its completion is:

**Javascript**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.c-sidebar-nav-item.c-sidebar-nav-dropdown').forEach(dropMenu => {
        dropMenu.addEventListener('click', () => dropMenu.classList.toggle('c-show'));
      });
    })
```

This script affects this element:

```
<li class="c-sidebar-nav-item c-sidebar-nav-dropdown">
```

Adding the `c-show` making it:

```
<li class="c-sidebar-nav-item c-sidebar-nav-dropdown">
```

I am trying to achieve the same thing with Blazor/C# via Interop.

So I have added the following to my element:

```
<li class="c-sidebar-nav-item c-sidebar-nav-dropdown" @onclick="dropMenu">
```

And my code section being:

```
@code {

  public async void dropMenu() 
  {
    classList.toggle('c-show')
  }
}
```

But I am not entirely sure on how get the result I am working for since all I know is that I need to adjust the javascript somehow but not sure on how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSInterop call from the OnAfterRenderAsync method to initialize your JavaScript object, this can be done only once, and then you can call your JavaScript methods each time the component is rendered.

Note: You need to inject the JSRuntime object in order to execute JSInterop calls.

```
 @page "/"
 @inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

 <li id="myid" @ref=MyElementReference class="c-sidebar-nav-item c-sidebar- 
                                        nav-dropdown" @onclick="dropMenu"> 

@code{
    // This add an element reference to the li element, which you can pass to 
    // your JavaScript functions
    ElementReference MyElementReference;

    // You have to call your JavaScript code after your components have been 
    // rendered. The OnAfterRenderAsync method is called after the component 
    // has been rendered, and thus you can put code here to initialize your 
    // component. This should be when firstRender is true, and multiple calls 
    // to your JavaScript objects, when firstRender is false.

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        // Note: Here you initialize your elements, only once. When the user 
        // clicks on the li element, you'll call your required method from 
        // the click event handler dropMenu

        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("MyJSMethods.myMethod", 
                    MyElementReference);
        }

    }
}



public async void dropMenu() 
  {
    await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("MyJSMethods.myMethod", 
                        MyElementReference);

  }
```

Place your script at the bottom of the _Host.cshtml file, just below
Adjust your element accordingly. Note the code here only display the alert with the id given to the li tag. Instead, you'll have to add the code to change your objects as necessary.

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<script>
        window.MyJSMethods =
        {
            myMethod: function (element) {
                window.alert(element.id);
            }
        };
    </script>
```

Note that the parameter named *element* that the function takes is an element object because we defined the argument as ElementReference in Blazor. Of course, you could've passed the element id or class name, etc.

Comment: is the function (element) { where I input the JS script?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: so my JS is dropMenu.classList.toggle('c-show')); that will make the adjustment to the DOM. So in the script tag, after function (element) { where it says window.alert do I write in the js script dropMenu.classList.toggle('c-show')); ?

Comment: MyJSMethods.myMethod is the name of your js function you are calling from the dropMenu Blazor method. Note that we pass to the js function a parameter called MyElementReference. This parameter is a Blazor object that becomes a JavaScript element in the MyJSMethods.myMethod method. This is why you can reference the element.id directly. The element object stands for the li element I've given the id = "myid" . Got it ?

Comment: Now, in the MyJSMethods.myMethod method, instead of displaying the alert window, put JavaScript that acts on the element object, as for instance, element.setAttribute("disabled", "");

Comment: ok i understand but what i have different js scripts i need to add in?

Comment: nevermind. looks like what i want is just to add other functions.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to create a module (`sidebar-dropdown.js`, for instance) with the following content:

```
export function addCShowTogglers() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.c-sidebar-nav-item.c-sidebar-nav-dropdown').forEach(dropMenu => {
        dropMenu.addEventListener('click', () => dropMenu.classList.toggle('c-show'));
    });
}
```

The next step involves creating a component like so:

```
@using Microsoft.JSInterop;
@implements IAsyncDisposable
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<ul>
    <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item c-sidebar-nav-dropdown">
        Content here
    </li>
    <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item c-sidebar-nav-dropdown">
        Content here
    </li>
    <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item c-sidebar-nav-dropdown">
        Content here
    </li>
</ul>
@code {
    private IJSObjectReference? _module; // requires .NET 5.0 or later

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            // this statement assumes the module is in the wwwroot/js folder
            _module = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/sidebar-dropdown.js");
            await _module.InvokeVoidAsync("addCShowTogglers");
        }
    }

    async ValueTask IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (_module != null)
        {
            // release unmanaged resources, eventually
            await _module.DisposeAsync();
            _module = null;
        }
    }
}
```